# Loop through div IDs with Javascript and display style associated with a clicked ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, user-interface

I'm trying to build a simple game aid for my 4-year-old who's into geography. I use Codepen for that: https://codepen.io/micsad/pen/PjNVpX

The idea is to roll the dice to pick a continent. Then roll the dice again to pick a country from that continent. Then roll the dice one last time to pick a city from that country.

I want us to have a simple interface that would help us navigate continents, countries and cities as we roll the dice. Try it with Europe and France in the pen I link to.

I use overlays tied to div IDs to enable this kind of navigation. This is JS that activates "Europe overlay" style:

```
function europeon() {
document.getElementById("overlay-europe").style.display = "block";
}

function europeoff() {
document.getElementById("overlay-europe").style.display = "none";
}
```

If every continent and country acts that same way, I'll end up with a large number of div IDs that will need their JS to make the interface work.

Is there a way to make JS loop through div IDs and display style associated with the one that is clicked?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can do it with programming. You need to build an Object containing the entire tree, then build your `div`s and click handlers based on that.

Comment: I'd appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I would really like to help, but I'd end up writing the entire thing for you. There's really nothing I can tell you other than to use loops and build HTML / add event listeners. If you don't know how to do that, learn how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to reuse the divs representing the die sides, instead of creating separate divs for each (sub)value-set. 
By using a data structure that can contain subvalues, the click can be general in a way that the subvalues of an active set can be used.
An example is added below. It doesn't contain all values, but the data structure should be easily expandable. It's a basic example and doesn't do things as change the background color, but that can be coupled to the `cur` object (e.g. a 'level' and setting a specific class based on the level)

```js
//note: the example makes use of ES6 methods and syntax

const data = {
 Europe: {
   France: ["Paris", "Lyon", "Cannes", "Saint-Tropez", "Marseille", "Avignon"],
    Poland:["Warschau"],
    Croatia:["Zagreb"],
   Germany: ["Berlin","Hamburg"],
    Spain:["Madrid", "Barcelona"],
    Ireland: ["Dublin"]
  },
  Asia: {
   Japan: ["Tokyo"]
  },
  "North and Central America":{
   
  },
  Africa:{
  
  },
  "South America":{
  
  },
  "Australia and Oceani":{
  
  }
};

const sides = [...document.querySelectorAll('div.side')]; //get a reference to all side divs (another option would be to generate the html dynamically)

let cur = {props : [], obj:data}; //active object

function set(obj){ //sets 'curprops' and fills the sides with the appropiate text
 cur.obj = obj || data; //if obj is null, end of the line is reached and initial 'data' is used
 cur.props = Array.isArray(cur.obj) ? cur.obj : Object.getOwnPropertyNames(cur.obj); 
  for(let i=0; i < sides.length; i++){ //set the text of each side
   sides[i].querySelector('.table-cell').textContent = i < cur.props.length ? cur.props[i] : ''; //the check if i < the number of props might be redundant if all values are guaranteed to have (at least) 6 values, but otherwise empties all other sides
  }  
}

set(); //first call to set the initial values

for(let i=0;i<6;i++) //bind each side to its own click event (note 'let' instead of 'var' is important here)
 sides[i].onclick = function(){
   set(cur.obj[cur.props[i]]);
  }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}
.side {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100%/ 7);
  margin: 1%;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / 7);
  background-color: none;
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5%;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display:  table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;  
}



.one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
}

.dice {
  display: table-cell;
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 250%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;  
}
```

```html
<div id= "overlay">

<div class="side"> 
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell"></div>
      <div class="one"><div class="dice">1</div></div>     
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>  

<div class="side">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell"></div>
      <div class="one"><div class="dice">2</div></div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="side">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell"></div>
      <div class="one"><div class="dice">3</div></div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div> 
<div class="side">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell"></div>
      <div class="one"><div class="dice">4</div></div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div> 
<div class="side">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell"></div>
      <div class="one"><div class="dice">5</div></div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div> 

<div class="side">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="table">
      <div class="table-cell"></div>
      <div class="one"><div class="dice">6</div></div>
    </div>  
  </div>  
</div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! There's a lot to unpack for me in this approach but it pretty much gets the job done.